# Pandas - count repeated values

Tags: python, pandas

With this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'players.name': ['John', 'Will' ,'John', 'Jim', 'Tim', 'John', 'Will', 'Tim'],
                    'players.diff': [0,0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]})
```

But 'players.name' values are repeated many times, and I need to count the number os times each unique name appears, adding a column 'count', with this value, ending up with:

```
  players.name  players.diff  counts
0         John             0       3
1         Will             0       2
2         John             0       0
3          Jim             0       1
4          Tim             0       2
5         John             0       0
6         Will             0       2
7          Tim             0       2
```

---

How do I do this?

Comment: Hi, 5k rep user, you should already know this :) but can you please add a [mcve] that demonstrates what you're trying to do please?

Comment: have you tried `df['players.diff'].unique()` or `df['players.diff'].nunique()`?

Comment: @cs95 thanks for the link,  219,770k rep user. sorry for that.

Comment: @DeepSpace Hmm...I may have misinterpreted what OP is asking.  I'll leave it up because I own my mistakes!

Comment: @cs95, please refer to edit.

Comment: @MarkMoretto hope it's clearer now

Comment: For sure.  I thought your post got deleted or something? Anyway, try: `counts_df = df.groupby("players.name").size().to_frame('counts').reset_index()` then `df = df.merge(counts_df, how='left', on="players.name")`.

Comment: yep, go ahead, thanks

Comment: @8-BitBorges Actually, I just edited that prev. comment.  I used `groupby()` then `merge()`, which might work for you.  If not, on merge you can set the 'how' parameter to 'outer' or 'left' to capture all values.  I think default is 'inner'.

Comment: Why does `John` show a count of zero when it appears three times?